# How do you fix the loop command in Discord.JS

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a Looping command on my Discord Bot where you can repeat songs in a voice channel. Although when I run the command, it shows a message that its going to loop the current song:

[image: Screenshot on Loop Command]

But then when the song ends (it should repeat itself again) the bot disconnects from voice channel. It uses YTDL-Core. Any Idea on how to solve this?
Repeat.JS

```js
let { RichEmbed } = require('discord.js')
const config = require('../../config.json')

exports.run = async(client, msg, args) => {
  const serverQueue = client.queue.get(msg.guild.id);
  if (!msg.member.voiceChannel) return msg.channel.send('You are not in a voice channel!');
  if(!serverQueue) return msg.channel.send('Not playing anything right now');
  if(serverQueue.voiceChannel.id !== msg.member.voiceChannel.id) return msg.channel.send(`You must be in **${serverQueue.voiceChannel.name}** to loop the queue`);
  serverQueue.loop = !serverQueue.loop;
  client.queue.set(msg.guild.id, serverQueue);
  if(serverQueue.loop) return msg.channel.send('** Repeated current queue!**');
  return msg.channel.send('** Unrepeated current queue!**');
}




exports.conf = {
    aliases: ['loop'],
    cooldown: "3"
}

exports.help = {
    name: "repeat",
    description: "Repeat the queue",
    usage: "repeat"
}
```

Queue.JS

```js
const { RichEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const { chunk } = require('../../util.js');

exports.run = async (client, msg, args) => {
    try{
        const serverQueue = client.queue.get(msg.guild.id);
        if(!serverQueue) return msg.channel.send('**Music  |** There is no music playing!\n\nPlay some music with **n!play <YouTube URL>** or **n!play <word>**.');
        let queues = [];
        serverQueue.songs.forEach((x, i) => {
            if(i !== 0){
                queues.push(x);
            }
        });
        const embed = new RichEmbed()
    .setColor('0xd677ff');
        if(!queues || queues.length < 1) return msg.channel.send(`**Music  |** **Now playing »** **${serverQueue.songs[0].title}**`, {embed: embed.setDescription('**Music  |** **There are no songs in the queue**')});
        if(queues.length > 10){
            let index = 0;
            queues = queues.map((x, i) => `\`${i +1}\`. __**[${x.title}](${x.url})**__ **by** *${msg.author.username}*`);
            queues = chunk(queues, 10);
      embed.setAuthor('Music ', 'https://i.imgur.com/s6OpKNC.jpg')
            embed.setDescription(queues[index].join('\n'));
            embed.setFooter(`Page ${index+1} of ${queues.length}`);
            const queuesMess = await msg.channel.send(`**Music  |** **Now playing »** ${serverQueue.songs[0].title}`, {embed: embed});
            await queuesMess.react('⬅');
      await queuesMess.react('');
            await queuesMess.react('➡');
      awaitReactions();
            function awaitReactions(){
                const filter = (rect, usr)=> ['⬅', '➡'].includes(rect.emoji.name) && usr.id === msg.author.id;
                queuesMess.createReactionCollector(filter, {time: 30000, max: 1})
                .on('collect', col => {
          if(col.emoji.name === '') return queuesMess.delete();
                    if(col.emoji.name === '⬅') index--;
                    if(col.emoji.name === '➡') index++;
                    index = ((index % queues.length) + queues.length) % queues.length;
                    embed.setAuthor('Music ', 'https://i.imgur.com/s6OpKNC.jpg')
          embed.setDescription(queues[index].join('\n'));
                    embed.setFooter(`Page ${index+1} of ${queues.length}`);
                    queuesMess.edit(`**Music  |** **Now playing »** ${serverQueue.songs[0].title}`, {embed: embed});
                    return awaitReactions();
                });
            }
        }else{
            embed.setDescription(queues.map((x, i) => `\`${i +1}\`. __**[${x.title}](${x.url})**__ **by** *${msg.author.username}*`).join('\n'));
            return msg.channel.send(`**Music  |** **Now playing »** ${serverQueue.songs[0].title}`, {embed: embed});
        }
    }catch(e){
        return msg.channel.send(`**Music  |** **Error Occured** :( \`\`\`${e.stack}\`\`\`try again later`);
    }
}

exports.conf = {
    aliases: [],
    cooldown: "3"
}

exports.help = {
    name: "queue",
    description: "Show music queue in this server",
    usage: "queue"
}
```

Main.JS

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const YouTube = require('simple-youtube-api');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const queue = new Map();
const client = new Discord.Client({disableEveryone: true});
const api = require("./app");
const fs = require('fs' );
let config = require('./config.json');
var servers = {};
let prefix = config.prefix;
const youtube = new YouTube(config.youtube_api);
const {Util, RichEmbed } = require('discord.js')
const stations = require('./stations.json')
const SBL = require("spacebots");
const DiscordBotListAPI = require('dbl-api');
const DBL = require("dblapi.js");
const dbl = new DBL('DBL CODE',client);
const Owner = config.Owner;
const util = require('./util.js')
const { get } = require('node-superfetch');
const { load } = require('cheerio');
const number = ['1⃣', '2⃣', '3⃣', '4⃣', '5⃣', '6⃣', '7⃣', '8⃣', '9⃣'];
var guild = {};
client.config = config;
client.util = util
client.queue = queue
client.on("ready", () => {
console.log(`Starting Nate Bot Version » 5.0`)
})

client.config = config;


fs.readdir("./events/", (err, files) => {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  files.forEach(file => {
    const event = require(`./events/${file}`);
    let eventName = file.split(".")[0];
    client.on(eventName, event.bind(null, client));
  });
}); 

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

    fs.readdir('./commands/', (err, categories) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        console.log(`NateBot » Found total ${categories.length} category.`);
        categories.forEach(category => {
            fs.readdir(`./commands/${category}`, (err, files) => {
                console.log(`NateBot » Found total ${files.length} command from ${category}.`)
                if (err) console.log(err);
                let commands = new Array();
                files.forEach(file => {
                    //delete require.cache[require.resolve(`./commands/${category}/${file}`)];
                    if (!file.endsWith('.js')) return;
                    let prop = require(`./commands/${category}/${file}`);
                    let cmdName = file.split('.')[0];
                   client.commands.set(cmdName, prop)
                })
            })
        })
    })



/*
  fs.readdir("./commands/admin/", (err, files) =>{
    if(err) return console.error(err);
    files.forEach(file => {
      if(!file.endsWith(".js")) return;
      let props = require(`./commands/admin/${file}`);
      let commandName = file.split(".")[0];
      client.commands.set(commandName, props);
    });
  });*/

exports.handleVideo = handleVideo
exports.queue = queue;
exports.youtube = youtube;
exports.queue = queue
exports.youtube = youtube;
  exports.ytdl = ytdl;
  exports.guild = guild;
  exports.config = config;

  client.on("message", async message =>{
 if(message.author.bot) return;
  if(message.channel.type === "dm") return;


    var args2 = message.content.substring(config.prefix.length).split(" ");
    if (!message.content.startsWith(config.prefix)) return;
  var searchString = args2.slice(0).join(' ');
  var url = args2[1] ? args2[1].replace(/<(.+)>/g, '$1') : '';
  var serverQueue = queue.get(message.guild.id);
    switch (args2[0].toLowerCase()) {
      case "skip":
    if (!message.member.voiceChannel) return message.channel.send(' **Music  |** You must connect to a Voice Channel.');
    if (!serverQueue) return message.channel.send('**Music  |** There is no music playing!\n\nPlay some music with **n!play <YouTube URL>** or **n!play <word>**.');
    serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.end('NateBot » Skip command has been used!');
    const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setColor('#0xa8a8a8')
      .setAuthor('Music ', 'https://i.imgur.com/Fm1edxi.png')
      .setDescription('Song Successfully Skipped ⏩')
      message.channel.send({embed});      
        return undefined; 
        break;
      case "np":
    if (!serverQueue) return message.channel.send('**Music  |** There is no music playing!\n\nPlay some music with **n!play <YouTube URL>** or **n!play <word>**.');

        let nowplayingemb = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setColor('#0x76d6ff')
    .setAuthor('Music ', 'https://i.imgur.com/Fm1edxi.png')
    .setThumbnail("https://thumbs.gfycat.com/UnkemptWhiteKakapo-small.gif")
    .setDescription('**Now Playing** ')
    .addField('Song Name', `**${serverQueue.songs[0].title}**`, true)

    return message.channel.send(nowplayingemb);
break;
 case "queue":
    if (!serverQueue) return message.channel.send('**Music  |** There is no music playing right now!\n\nPlay some music with **n!play <YouTube URL>** or **n!play <word>**.');
        let queueemb = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setAuthor('Music ', 'https://i.imgur.com/s6OpKNC.jpg')
        .setTitle(`**Queue for ${message.guild.name}**`)
        .setDescription(`${serverQueue.songs.map(song => `**»** [${song.title}](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${song.id}})`).join('\n')}`)
        .setColor(`0xd677ff`)
    return message.channel.send(queueemb)
break;   
 case "leave":
    if (!message.member.voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('**Music  |** You must connect to a Voice Channel.');
        let stopemb = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor(0xff7777)
    .setAuthor(`Music `, 'https://i.imgur.com/Fm1edxi.png')
    .setDescription("Successfully Disconnected... ❌");
    message.guild.me.voiceChannel.leave();
  return message.channel.send(stopemb)
  break;
}
  })

async function handleVideo(video, message, voiceChannel, playlist = false) {
  var serverQueue = queue.get(message.guild.id);
 // console.log(video);
  var song = {
    id: video.id,
    title: video.title,
    url: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${video.id}`,
    channel: video.channel.title,
    durationm: video.duration.minutes,
    durations: video.duration.seconds,
    durationh: video.duration.hours,
    publishedAt: video.publishedAt,
  };
  if (!serverQueue) {
    var queueConstruct = {
      textChannel: message.channel,
      voiceChannel: voiceChannel,
      connection: null,
      songs: [],
      volume: 5,
      playing: true,
      loop: true
    };
    queue.set(message.guild.id, queueConstruct);

    queueConstruct.songs.push(song);

    try {
      var connection = await voiceChannel.join();
      var listener = await voiceChannel.join();
      connection.on('error', console.error);
      queueConstruct.connection = connection;
      play(message.guild, queueConstruct.songs[0]);
    } catch (error) {
      queue.delete(message.guild.id);
      return message.channel.send(`**Music  |** **Error Occured** ${error}`);
    }
  } else { 
    serverQueue.songs.push(song);
    //console.log(serverQueue.songs);
    if (playlist) return undefined;

    let queueemb = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setAuthor('Music ', 'https://i.imgur.com/s6OpKNC.jpg')
    .setTitle(`**Song Successfully Queued!** `)
    .setColor(`#0xd677ff`)
    .addField(`**Uploader**`, `${song.channel}`, true)
    .addField(`**Video ID**`, song.id , true)
    .setFooter(`Published » ${song.publishedAt}`)
    .addField(`**Duration**`, `**\`${song.durationh}\`** Hours, **\`${song.durationm}\`** Minutes and **\`${song.durations}\`** Seconds`, true)
    .setDescription(`[${song.title}](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${song.id}})`)
    .setThumbnail(`https://i.ytimg.com/vi/${song.id}/sddefault.jpg`)
    .setColor(`0xd677ff`)
    return message.channel.send(queueemb).then(msg => {
      message.delete(10000)
    })
  }
  return undefined;
}
  function play(guild, song) {
  var serverQueue = queue.get(guild.id);

  if (!song) {
    serverQueue.voiceChannel.leave();
    queue.delete(guild.id);
    return;
  }
  //console.log(serverQueue.songs);

  const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection.playStream(ytdl(song.url))

  .on('end', reason => {
      if (reason === 'NateBot » Stream is not generating quickly enough.') console.log('NateBot » Song ended.');
      else console.log(reason);
      serverQueue.songs.shift();
      play(guild, serverQueue.songs[0]);
    })
  .on('error', error => console.error(error));
  dispatcher.setVolumeLogarithmic(serverQueue.volume / 5);
    let playingemb = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setAuthor('Music ', 'https://i.imgur.com/s6OpKNC.jpg')
    .setTitle(`**Now Playing!** `)
    .setColor(`0x76d6ff`)
    .addField(`**Uploader**`, `${song.channel}`, true)
    .addField(`**Video ID**`, song.id , true)
    .setFooter(`Published » ${song.publishedAt}`)
    .addField(`**Duration**`, `**\`${song.durationh}\`** Hours, **\`${song.durationm}\`** Minutes and **\`${song.durations}\`** Seconds`, true)
    .setThumbnail(`https://i.ytimg.com/vi/${song.id}/sddefault.jpg`)
    .setDescription(`[${song.title}](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${song.id}})`)

    serverQueue.textChannel.send(playingemb);

}
// Optional events
dbl.on('posted', () => {
  console.log('Server count posted!');
  console.log('NateBot » Server count posted!');
})

client.login(config.Token);
dbl.on('error', e => {
 console.log(`Oops! ${e}`);
 console.log(`NateBot » Oops! ${e}`);
})

  api.startApp(client);

client.login(config.Token);
```

Thanks

Comment: Mind adding the code where the queue is actually played?

Comment: Sure, i will edit the post above to have them

Comment: Check above for the code

Answer (score 1):

Although you're setting the queue's loop option, I don't see you using it anywhere else. A simple solution to make the queue repeat would be to add the song that ended to the end of the queue again. For example...

```js
if (serverQueue.loop === true) serverQueue.songs.push(serverQueue.songs.shift());
else serverQueue.songs.shift();
play(guild, serverQueue.songs[0]);
```

The code above removes the element from the beginning of the array and adds it to the end if the queue should be looped. That way, it'll keep repeating the songs in order. If the queue shouldn't be looped, it simply removes the first song and that's it.

Comment: Thank you. I have fixed my Repeat command already with your advice! It works how it should